# Debugging failed peer discovery?

Tags: parity, nodes, node-discovery

I have a small private dev network.

There are three (Parity) nodes.  One of them shows two peers.  The other two each show one peer.  One of the nodes showing only one peer is listed in the genesis file.

What could be preventing the two nodes from discovering each other, especially since they each discover the third node?

More specifically: what can I start debugging/reading to find the failure point?

All three nodes have the following ports open:

30303 on tcp and udp
30304 on udp